# Linear Search in Lisp, array errors

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Simple Linear Search for an Input Parameter, cannot use built in functions like find, etc.

Unfortunately, I can't find a lot of appropriate documentation as it's either outdated and most don't cover a problem this simple.

Tips on understanding lisp are much appreciated.

```lisp
(defun search(numray x) 
    (defvar i 0)
    (loop for i in numray
        (cond
        ((= x (aref numray i) "Element is present in array")
        ((/= x (aref numray i) "Element is not present in array")
        (t "iddunno")))))
 ) 

(setf numray (make-array '(10)   
:initial-contents '(0 11 2 33 44 55 66 7 88 99)))
(defvar x (read))
(search arr x)
```

Check defined array for an input variable. State whether it exists or not.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It's not typical forum site. We are happy to help here, sometimes even with homework (oh come on, it's Lisp! what can be better?:), but can you please at least ask a question? I also suggest going through *What topics can I ask about here?* https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This a basic introduction into Lisp: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/
You can download a version of the book from there.

Comment: @RSM Thanks for the welcome, and sorry was just following the prompts -- noted for the future! I'm sure it's great to those that use it but I just want to burn it with fire right now 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(defun search(numray x) 
    (defvar i 0)
    (loop for i in numray
        (cond
        ((= x (aref numray i) "Element is present in array")
        ((/= x (aref numray i) "Element is not present in array")
        (t "iddunno")))))
 ) 

(setf numray (make-array '(10)   
:initial-contents '(0 11 2 33 44 55 66 7 88 99)))
(defvar x (read))
(search arr x)
```

The first thing you need to learn about Lisp is to indent your code according to the list structure:

```
(defun search (numray x) 
  (defvar i 0)
  (loop for i in numray
        (cond
         ((= x (aref numray i) "Element is present in array")
          ((/= x (aref numray i) "Element is not present in array")
           (t "iddunno")))))
  ) 

(setf numray (make-array '(10)   
                         :initial-contents '(0 11 2 33 44 55 66 7 88 99)))
(defvar x (read))
(search arr x)
```

Next:

- DEFVAR is for global variables, not local ones
- you don't need to declare `i`, since `LOOP` declares it
- you need to write a `DO` before the iteration forms in a `LOOP`
- the parentheses around the call to `=` are wrong
- the parentheses around the call to `/=` are wrong
- a vector can easily be written as #(1 2 3 4 5)
- put `*` around a global variable
- don't name your function `search`, because that function is already built-in
- `IN` works for lists, use `ACROSS` for vectors

Example:

```
CL-USER 3 > (defun note-num-in-array (vector number) 
              (loop for item across vector do
                    (print (if (= number item)
                               "Element is present in array"
                               "Element is not present in array"))))
NOTE-NUM-IN-ARRAY

CL-USER 4 > (note-num-in-array #(1 2 3 1 2 4 5 4 3 2) 2)

"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is present in array" 
"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is present in array" 
"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is not present in array" 
"Element is present in array" 
NIL
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew there was a really simple way and was looking at so many websites and couldn't piece it together. Also kept getting errors when trying to loop through the array but I guess that was because I was using in rather than across. Thanks for the reference material recommendations, I couldn't find much that was readable to me.